# Android Native SIP is not registering on Android 9 (API level 28)

Tags: android, android-service, sip

My below method is called on `onStartCommand` of Service class & is working perfectly for API level 27 and below. Then SIP call is initiated successfully without any issue.

But for API Level 28 sipManager not opening and `mSipManager.setRegistrationListener` is not called. So SIP `onRegistering`, `onRegistrationDone` or `onRegistrationFailed` is not called. No warning or error is found. What should I do for API level 28?

```
public void initializeLocalProfile() {
    try {
        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(sip_username, "" + sipServerDomain);
        builder.setPort(sipPort);
        builder.setPassword(sip_password);
        mSipProfile = builder.build();

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

        mSipManager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
        mSipManager.open(mSipProfile, pi, null);

        if (mSipManager.isOpened(sip_username + "@" + sipServerDomain)) {
            mSipManager.setRegistrationListener(mSipProfile.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Registering with SIP Server..., localProfileUri2: " + localProfileUri);
                }

                @Override
                public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "SIP onRegistrationDone, expiryTime: " + expiryTime);
                    ((AeroApplication) getApplication()).setRegisteredSIP(true);
                }

                @Override
                public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "SIP Registration failed :" + errorMessage + ", errorCode :" + errorCode);
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "SIP SipManager not opened, try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        Log.d(TAG, " SIP ParseException : " + pe.getMessage());
    } catch (SipException se) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SIP Exception: " + se.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?